# ValueError: array split does not result in an equal division, during training model

Tags: python, pytorch, torch, training-data, image-classification

I am attempting to training model using VIT to classify some images. During training the script stuck and I don't know where is my error. The classification features by some images with only two target 0 and 1 (false and true). The batch size is 32 and epochs are only 3.

Below I put the script for training model:

```
import torch.utils.data as data
from torch.autograd import Variable
import numpy as np
train_loader = data.DataLoader(train_ds, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, shuffle=True,  num_workers=2)
test_loader  = data.DataLoader(test_ds, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, shuffle=True, num_workers=2) 

# Train the model
for epoch in range(EPOCHS):        
  for step, (x, y) in enumerate(train_loader):
    # Change input array into list with each batch being one element
    x = np.split(np.squeeze(np.array(x)), BATCH_SIZE)
    # Remove unecessary dimension
    for index, array in enumerate(x):
      x[index] = np.squeeze(array)
    # Apply feature extractor, stack back into 1 tensor and then convert to tensor
    x = torch.tensor(np.stack(feature_extractor(x)['pixel_values'], axis=0))
    # Send to GPU if available
    x  = x.to(device)
    y = y.to(device)
    b_x = Variable(x)   # batch x (image)
    b_y = Variable(y)   # batch y (target)
    # Feed through model
    output = model(b_x, None)
    loss = output[0]
    # Calculate loss
    if loss is None: 
      loss = loss_func(output, b_y)   
      optimizer.zero_grad()           
      loss.backward()                 
      optimizer.step()

    if step % 50 == 0:
      # Get the next batch for testing purposes
      test = next(iter(test_loader))
      test_x = test[0]
      # Reshape and get feature matrices as needed
      test_x = np.split(np.squeeze(np.array(test_x)), BATCH_SIZE)
      for index, array in enumerate(test_x):
        test_x[index] = np.squeeze(array)
      test_x = torch.tensor(np.stack(feature_extractor(test_x)['pixel_values'], axis=0))
      # Send to appropirate computing device
      test_x = test_x.to(device)
      test_y = test[1].to(device)
      # Get output (+ respective class) and compare to target
      test_output, loss = model(test_x, test_y)
      test_output = test_output.argmax(1)
      # Calculate Accuracy
      accuracy = (test_output == test_y).sum().item() / BATCH_SIZE
      print('Epoch: ', epoch, '| train loss: %.4f' % loss, '| test accuracy: %.2f' % accuracy)
```

The error message is this: ValueError: array split does not result in an equal division. And it highlights the comand `x = np.split(np.squeeze(np.array(x)), BATCH_SIZE)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently came across the same error. Check with the length of the `train_ds`. and change the BATCH_SIZE so that when you divide the `len(train_ds)` by `BATCH_SIZE` the reminder is zero.

Comment: Hey the_mctfellow, welcome to Stack Overflow and thank you for your answer! The community would appreciate if you would improve your answer by extending it to include more concrete steps (for example, a code snippet) which explains how the stated question can be solved using this approach.